# Why is this Gulp error?

Tags: sass, gulp

Im following this tutorial to compile Sass with Gulp
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cg7lwX0u-U0
I think im doing the same as in the video but I get this error that I don't understand. 
I don't want to compress it, I just want to compile all my .scss files to a single styles.css file, as I do with Compass.

[image: error that Im getting and my settings]

Comment: Next time, paste the actual code and error instead of making a screenshot of everything.

Comment: Ok sorry, I thought it could be easier to understand since there was not much code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `gulp-ruby-sass` instead of the regular `gulp-sass`. `gulp-ruby-sass` does not use the `gulp.src()` command, instead you should give the path to it directly like this:

```
gulp.task('styles', function() {
    sass('sass/_*.scss')
      .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'));
});
```